# Why do generic extension methods compile, but not generic properties or methods in F#?

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I want to write a simple record which has a Min property, a Max property and a Step property. .NET 7+ offers the System.Numerics.INumber<'T> interface, so a first step would be

```
type RangeSetting<'T when 'T:> INumber<'T>> = 
  { Max: 'T;
    Min: 'T; 
    Step: 'T }
```

When I try to add a generic method or property like

```
   member range.OptionsCount =
    (range.Max - range.Min + range.Step) / range.Step
```

the compiler emits the following error

> This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable ^T when ^T :> INumber<^T> could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.

On the other hand, if I write it like this:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
[<Extension>]
type RangeSettingExtensions =
   [<Extension>]
   static member inline OptionsCount<'T when 'T:> INumber<'T>>(range: RangeSetting<'T>) =
    (range.Max - range.Min + range.Step) / range.Step
```

The compiler is ok with this.

Does anyone have a clue why? The question can be abstracted even more, but I assume it's easier to talk about something more concrete

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be this is related to how constraints for `+` and `-` operations are handled in F# (generic math was present there long before C# with `INumber<T>`) in combination with [Generic limitation of intrinsic and optional type extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#generic-limitation-of-intrinsic-and-optional-type-extensions). One way I was able to make it compiling was to use the the operations defined on `'T`:

```ml
type RangeSetting<'T when 'T:> INumber<'T>> = 
  { Max: 'T;
    Min: 'T; 
    Step: 'T } with
  member range.OptionsCount =
    'T.op_CheckedAddition('T.op_CheckedSubtraction(range.Max, range.Min), range.Step)
        /range.Min
```

Reported an issue for F# compiler team [@github](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/16464).